# Action Sequence

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

have the following code that runs when two objects collide.

```
var A = SKAction.scaleBy(0.1, duration: 0.52)
vanish.runAction(A)
```

Line 1 is running a scaling action and Line 2 is running that scaling action on the object I want.

But, how can I run some code at the END the action? Say, to change a score from 0 - 1?

At the moment I have something like this:

```
var A = SKAction.scaleBy(0.1, duration: 0.52)
vanish.runAction(A)

score = 1
```

But this doesn't wait for the action to finish.

I understand I need to use a action.sequence. I have that. But I don't know how to write an action that says "change value of variable from 0 to 1"

Thanks guys :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two options: you can pass a completion block to `runAction` that will be executed once the `SKAction` finishes. From the [documentation for `SKNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/):

> `func runAction(_ action: SKAction!, completion block: (() -> Void)!)`

You can then use this like so:

```
vanish.runAction(A) {
    score = 1
    // If `score` is a property of your class you'll need to use self.score
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `SKAction.runBlock` and use a sequence of `SKAction`s, for example:

```
let scale = SKAction.scaleBy(0.1, duration: 0.52)
let complete = SKAction.runBlock { score = 1 }

vanish.runAction(SKAction.sequence([scale, complete]))
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I ended up just putting the code i wanted exactly into the runBlock. I've spent hours trying to figure this out. Thank you so much :D

Comment: Glad it's all working for you :) Good luck with your project!